# code: 'Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized'

Tags: javascript, neo4j, driver

I am trying to connect neo4j with a javascript driver by below code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path'); 
var logger= require('morgan');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var neo4j= require('neo4j-driver');

var app=express(); 

//view Engine:
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
var driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost',neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j','5141'));
var session = driver.session();

app.get('/',function(req, res){
     session
          .run('MATCH(n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 25')
          .then(function(result){
               result.records.forEach(function(record){
           console.log(record._fields[0].properties);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
res.send('It works');
```

});

```
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server started on port 3000 ');
module.exports= app;
```

but I keep getting the 'Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized' message in terminal. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: please share your neo4j.conf file located in $NEO4J_HOME/conf folder

Comment: I have tried to delete the auth file but after that I face below error.                    Database failed to start: Neo4jError: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser,

Comment: If you remove the auth file, the default credentials will be generated again and you will have to change the default password (easiest way to do that is to connect with Neo4j Desktop).

Comment: I want to see the configuration file (neo4j.conf) then you deleted auth file. I pass this SO, next!  Lolz

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to delete the neo4j and installed a new one and solved the issue